# Curious question about passing variables to components

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to understand the basics of vue.js and there is this thing that is bugging me out. I have this component called `host` which is passed a variable called `passed-Variable`. How come I can refer to it as `passedVariable` (camel-case instead of delimiter-separated) inside my component, even though it is passed to the component as `passed-Variable`?

Here is a code example for clarification:

#### Index

```
<div id="app">
    <host :passed-Variable="'test'"></host>
</div>
```

#### host.vue

```
<template>
    <span>
        {{ passedVariable }}  
    </span>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'passedVariable'
        ]
    }
</script>
```

This question might sound stupid if you're experienced with vue but please have in mind that I have absolutely no experience of it at all :)

Comment: Refer to the [part about prop casing](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case) in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Vue.js official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

> HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, so browsers will interpret any uppercase characters as lowercase. That means when you’re using in-DOM templates, **camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased (hyphen-delimited) equivalents:**

```
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  // camelCase in JavaScript
  props: ['postTitle'],
  template: '<h3>{{ postTitle }}</h3>'
})

<!-- kebab-case in HTML -->
<blog-post post-title="hello!"></blog-post>
```

---

Furthermore, in your example: `passed-Variable` should be `passed-variable` (without uppercase).

Answer (score 1):

> How come I can refer to it as passedVariable (camel-case instead of delimiter-separated) inside my component, even though it is passed to the component as passed-Variable

Because the html is gone almost immediately:

As soon as this runs (or even sooner in case of `*.vue` files / other pre-compilation) the (html-) template is transformend into a renderFunction(= javascript) where it has to adhere to js naming conventions; `-` is not allowed in js names.

So there is this convention about how html "names" and js "names" are mapped.